# Is my reputation stuck?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

E.g. 6 minutes ago, I received another upvote from [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66481/do-shrines-recharge/66490#66490), however my rating is still that of several hours ago. I already noticed this problem a couple of hours ago, but I hoped it would just go away.

What's going on? Do the Prime Evils of Hell prevent me from reaching 5k?

edit: little update: just now, I received two upvotes [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66610/is-there-a-way-to-keep-my-map-visible-while-i-walk-around/66612#66612), but my reputation only went up by 10 points.

edit2: Actually, now that I look at it, my profile reputation history shows a whole bunch of events with no green "+some number" showing up to the left of it, or wrong numbers (where it would usually show "+20" when I got two upvotes).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You hit the daily rep cap.  Reputation from upvotes is limited to +200 per day.  Bounties and accepted answers (+2 for making a check or +15 for receiving a check) do not count towards the cap.

In your case you got 234 rep yesterday (days here are UTC).  Two of your answers were accepted (+15 × 2) and you accepted two as well (+2 × 2), so total bonus = 34 on top of the 200 cap.

Comment: Can I read about the purpose of that cap anywhere?

Comment: @heishe it promotes continued participation, as well as blocks massive reputation gains which can lead to people earning privileges before they know their broader purpose (or outright fraud).

Comment: Ok, thanks :--) (extra long nose for character minimum)

Comment: @heishe There are also two nice and rare bagdes that involve daily cap: Epic (reach the cap 50 times) and Legendary (reach the cap 150 times).

Comment: @Drake and Mortarboard (for doing it the first time)